# Reference to application users always returning null even though included

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My Club has many members so I have added the following virtual property Members my question is when I want to list the club members shouldn't adding just the virtual load this into lazy loading am using .net 5.0.1 at present.

```
var members =  _context.Clubs.Include(c=>c.Members).Where(w => w.ClubId == tennantId ).ToList();
```

When I look at var members even when the members have been included it is zero even though the teannatId matches.

```
public class MSFSAddonDBContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MSFSAddonDBContext(DbContextOptions<MSFSAddonDBContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }
     public DbSet<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
     public virtual List<ApplicationUser>? Members { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my controller method.

```
public void  IActionResult ClubMembers()
{
    var tennantId =  GetTennantId().Result;
    var members =  _context.Clubs.Include(c=>c.Members).Where(w => w.ClubId == tennantId ).ToList();
    return View(members);
}
```

There are two members references at top level and inside the clubs.

This is the club class

```
public  class Club
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? TeannatId { get; set; }
    public Guid? ClubId { get; set; }
    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }       
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public string? Url { get; set; }
    public int? ClubLikes { get; set; }
    public int? ClubDislikes { get; set; }
    public int? MembersCount { get; set; }
    public string? Logo { get; set; }
    public List<Flight>? Flights { get; set; }
    public string? ThumbNail { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? GpdrRemoveRequestDate { get; set; }
    public bool? isGpdrRemoveRequest { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? BannedTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? BanPeriod { get; set; }
    public bool? isBanned { get; set; }
    public bool? isActive { get; set; }
    public bool? isDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ApplicationUser>? Members { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit 2**

This is the application user class.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public enum UserTypeEnum
    {
        Guest=0,
        User=1,
        Author=2,
        AddonOwner=3,
        GroupOwner=5,
        ClubMember=6,
        ClubAdmin=7,
        SuperAdmin=199,
        BandUser=999
    }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? GamerTag { get; set; }
    public bool? isOnline { get; set; }
    public int? UserType { get; set; }
    public Guid? TennantId { get; set; }
    public Guid? ClubId { get; set; }
    public List<Badges>? Badges { get; set; }
}
```

NB As always with ef the primary keys in all my tables are the Id column thanks

Comment: Could you add the ApplicationUser class and the relation setup between them (if there is one) to your question please. (Also include what the primary keys are please)

Comment: @BenceL please see above edits

Comment: Did you create a new migration? In the Club class you have Id and ClubId as well (which one is the primary key?), you should clean up your classes. Try adding `public Club Club { get; set; }` to `ApplicationUser`

Comment: The primary key as stated is Id for all tables that was set in their ok will try

Comment: But a user could belong to many clubs

Comment: In that case you need to setup a many-to-many relation between them. You stated that you use .NET 5, so here is an example (the official docs): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many